# Iterating a function over data, and then separating the results into different objects

Tags: r, object, iteration, repeat, lm

I'm interested in iterating some functions in r.

Specifically, I want to run code on the `diamonds` dataset using a linear model where the IV is `price` and the DVs that vary from one model to another, using the variables `carat`, `x`, `y`, and `z`. I want these individual models to be stored in unique objects (e.g., for `carat` the name would be `lm_IV_price_carat`, and for `x` the names of the object would be ```lm_IV_price_x````).

I then want to use these unique objects to create unique objects with the summaries of the lm() objects (e.g., the summary of `lm_IV_price_carat` would be called `summary_lm_IV_price_carat`, and the summary of `lm_IV_price_x` would be `summary_lm_IV_price_x`).

I can do this the long way without iteration, but is this possible to do with less code? If so, how would this be done?

---

---

EDIT 1: Changed title slightly and made example more shorter and more specific.

I was told it would be a good idea to make the example more specific.

What I want to do is run the same basic code set on a variety of different variables over and over without having to repeat and write out all of the code every time I want to change variables. I can do it the long way, but I don't know how to do it in a shorter manner in r. I want to know if there is a way to do it in a shorter manner.

Here is what I want to do, and the corresponding code, using the long version:

(1) Create a generic lm() object that varies only in terms of DV used, starting with ```carat``.

```
#### creates lm()
lm_IV_price <- lm(carat ~ price, data = diamonds)
```

(2) Create a generic summary() object of the lm object, starting with `carat`.

```
#### creates summary of data
summary_lm_IV_price <- summary(lm_IV_price)
```

(3) Give unique names for these lm() and summary() generic objects.

```
#### creates unique names for lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_lm_IV_price <- paste("lm_IV_price","_",as.character(lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_lm_IV_price, lm_IV_price)

#### creates unique names for summary_lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_summary_lm_IV_price <- paste("summary_lm_IV_price","_",as.character(summary_lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_summary_lm_IV_price, summary_lm_IV_price)
```

(4) Repeat steps 1-3 using the variables `x`, `y`, and `z`. Please see the code below for how I did this the long way (i.e., I copied the first code set and then used find and replace).

I want to know if there is a way to do this task more quickly using a smaller amount of r code.

---

---

Here is the code for the long version:

```
# loads ggplot2 package
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")} # ---- NOTE: relates to mlm analyses


# runs lm, and summary

## when DV = carat

### creates general model objects

#### creates lm()
lm_IV_price <- lm(carat ~ price, data = diamonds)

#### creates summary of data
summary_lm_IV_price <- summary(lm_IV_price)

### creates unique names for general model objects

#### creates unique names for lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_lm_IV_price <- paste("lm_IV_price","_",as.character(lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_lm_IV_price, lm_IV_price)

#### creates unique names for summary_lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_summary_lm_IV_price <- paste("summary_lm_IV_price","_",as.character(summary_lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_summary_lm_IV_price, summary_lm_IV_price)

## when DV = x

### creates general model objects

#### creates lm()
lm_IV_price <- lm(x ~ price, data = diamonds)

#### creates summary of data
summary_lm_IV_price <- summary(lm_IV_price)

### creates unique names for general model objects

#### creates unique names for lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_lm_IV_price <- paste("lm_IV_price","_",as.character(lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_lm_IV_price, lm_IV_price)

#### creates unique names for summary_lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_summary_lm_IV_price <- paste("summary_lm_IV_price","_",as.character(summary_lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_summary_lm_IV_price, summary_lm_IV_price)

## when DV = y

### creates general model objects

#### creates lm()
lm_IV_price <- lm(y ~ price, data = diamonds)

#### creates summary of data
summary_lm_IV_price <- summary(lm_IV_price)

### creates unique names for general model objects

#### creates unique names for lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_lm_IV_price <- paste("lm_IV_price","_",as.character(lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_lm_IV_price, lm_IV_price)

#### creates unique names for summary_lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_summary_lm_IV_price <- paste("summary_lm_IV_price","_",as.character(summary_lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_summary_lm_IV_price, summary_lm_IV_price)

## when DV = z

### creates general model objects

#### creates lm()
lm_IV_price <- lm(z ~ price, data = diamonds)

#### creates summary of data
summary_lm_IV_price <- summary(lm_IV_price)

### creates unique names for general model objects

#### creates unique names for lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_lm_IV_price <- paste("lm_IV_price","_",as.character(lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_lm_IV_price, lm_IV_price)

#### creates unique names for summary_lm_IV_price
# ---- NOTE: generates name to use for object created
name_summary_lm_IV_price <- paste("summary_lm_IV_price","_",as.character(summary_lm_IV_price$call$formula[[2]]), sep = "")
# ---- NOTE: creates unique object
assign(name_summary_lm_IV_price, summary_lm_IV_price)

## displays unique models objects

### lm() objects

#### recalls unique lm() objects
apropos("lm_IV_price")

#### displays unique lm() objects
lm_IV_price_carat
lm_IV_price_x
lm_IV_price_y
lm_IV_price_z

## displays unique models objects

### lm() objects

#### recalls unique lm() objects
apropos("summary_lm_IV_price")

#### displays unique lm() objects
summary_lm_IV_price_carat
summary_lm_IV_price_x
summary_lm_IV_price_y
summary_lm_IV_price_z
```

Comment: Can you make this example minimal and show which part of the code would you like to change?

Comment: I tried to do so. Not sure how successful I was at this task, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants

- to fit a number of linear models using different formulae,
- create summaries of each of the models,
- and create individual objects in the global environment, finally.

My preferred way is to keep equally structured data together in a larger data object, e.g., a *list*, as long as possible in order avoid cluttering the workspace with many single objects. However, if the OP insists individual objects can be created easily from a named list using `list2env()`.

Well, here is what I would do

#### Creating a list of fitted models

```
# define variables
ivar <- "price"
dvars <- setdiff(names(ggplot2::diamonds), ivar)[c(1, 7:9)] # carat, x, y, z

# create character vectors of formulae and names 
formulae <- paste(dvars, "~", ivar)
lm_names <- sprintf("lm_IV_%s_%s", ivar, dvars)

# loop over formulae to fit models
lm_list <- lapply(formulae, function(f) eval(bquote(lm(.(f), data = ggplot2::diamonds))))
# name list elements
lm_list <- setNames(lm_list, lm_names)

lm_list
```

> ```
> $lm_IV_price_carat
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "carat ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)        price  
>   0.3672972    0.0001095  
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_x
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "x ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)        price  
>   4.7531182    0.0002487  
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_y
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "y ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)        price  
>   4.7601319    0.0002478  
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_z
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "z ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)        price  
>   2.9395800    0.0001523
> ```

lm_list is a list containing the results from fitting the four models. The list elements are named as requested by the OP.

It is straightforward to apply the `summary()` function (or any other suitable function, e.g., `coef()`) on each of the models in the list:

```
lapply(lm_list, summary)
```

> ```
> $lm_IV_price_carat
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "carat ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -1.35765 -0.11329 -0.02442  0.10344  2.66973 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 3.673e-01  1.112e-03   330.2   <2e-16 ***
> price       1.095e-04  1.986e-07   551.4   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.184 on 53938 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8493,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8493 
> F-statistic: 3.041e+05 on 1 and 53938 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_x
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "x ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -9.2380 -0.4204  0.0200  0.3935  2.8574 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 4.753e+00  3.165e-03  1501.7   <2e-16 ***
> price       2.487e-04  5.650e-07   440.2   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.5235 on 53938 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.7822,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7822 
> F-statistic: 1.937e+05 on 1 and 53938 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_y
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "y ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Residuals:
>    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
> -9.228 -0.416  0.022  0.392 51.115 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 4.760e+00  3.460e-03  1375.8   <2e-16 ***
> price       2.478e-04  6.176e-07   401.1   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.5723 on 53938 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.749,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.7489 
> F-statistic: 1.609e+05 on 1 and 53938 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
>
>
> $lm_IV_price_z
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = "z ~ price", data = ggplot2::diamonds)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -5.8019 -0.2669  0.0090  0.2482 28.5603 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 2.940e+00  2.168e-03  1355.7   <2e-16 ***
> price       1.523e-04  3.871e-07   393.6   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.3586 on 53938 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.7418,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7417 
> F-statistic: 1.549e+05 on 1 and 53938 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

The result is a named list again.

#### Creating unique objects in the workspace

I would continue to work with lists but the OP has requested that *individual models to be stored in unique objects*.

This can be achieved by

```
list2env(lm_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

which creates four objects in the workspace:

```
apropos("lm_IV")
```

> ```
> [1] "lm_IV_price_carat" "lm_IV_price_x"     "lm_IV_price_y"     "lm_IV_price_z"
> ```

Creating unique objects for the summaries is a bit more tedious because we have to rename the list elements:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
lapply(lm_list, summary) %>% 
  set_names(paste0("summary_", names(.))) %>% 
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)

apropos("summary_lm_IV")
```

> ```
> [1] "summary_lm_IV_price_carat" "summary_lm_IV_price_x"     "summary_lm_IV_price_y"    
> [4] "summary_lm_IV_price_z"
> ```

#### Explanation of `eval(bquote(lm(.(f), data = ggplot2::diamonds))))`

My first attempt was

```
lm_list <- lapply(formulae, function(f) lm(f, data = ggplot2::diamonds))
```

which worked fine except that the formula `carat ~ price`, e.g., vanished from the output of lm()`and`summary()`:

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = f, data = ggplot2::diamonds)
> ```

Note that the formula information is still contained in the models which can be demonstrated by

```
lapply(formulae, function(f) format(terms(lm(f, data = ggplot2::diamonds))))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "carat ~ price"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "x ~ price"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "y ~ price"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "z ~ price"
> ```

The article [R Tip: How to Pass a formula to lm](https://win-vector.com/2018/09/01/r-tip-how-to-pass-a-formula-to-lm/) by *John Mount* suggested to use the `eval()`, `bquote()`, `.()` pattern.

Alternatively, `wrapr::let()` works as well:

```
lapply(dvars, function(dv) wrapr::let(c(DV = dv, IV = "price"), lm(DV ~ IV, data = ggplot2::diamonds)))
```

or

```
lapply(dvars, function(dv) wrapr::let(c(DV = dv), lm(DV ~ price, data = ggplot2::diamonds)))
```

Comment: This approach seems to solve my current issue real well. Thanks for all of your help. It's greatly appreciated.